# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens in Microservices

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I've developed code which enables secure communication between client and server. I took code reference from : https://github.com/piomin/sample-spring-cloud-netflix/tree/security.

In this example, I created `keystore.p12` using following commands.

```
keytool -genkey -alias client -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
```

The `sample-discovery-service`, `application.yml` details are as follows -

```
spring:  
  application:
    name: discovery-service

server:  
  port: ${PORT:8761}

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    secure-port-enabled: true
    non-secure-port-enabled: false
    status-page-url: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/info
    health-check-url: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/health
    home-page-url: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}

security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  user:
    name: admin
    password: admin123
```

and `sample-client-service`, `application.yml` details

```
spring:  
  application:
    name: client-service

server:  
  port: ${PORT:8081}
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-password: 123456
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: client

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://admin:admin123@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

and when I launch: https://localhost:8761/info. I get the below error -

```
2018-12-22 22:54:33.744  INFO 5576 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance CLIENT-SERVICE/localhost:client-service:8081 with status UP (replication=false)
2018-12-22 22:54:39.495  INFO 5576 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:683) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

Edit-1:

**EDIT-1**

After making the suggested changes, now getting below error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8761 failed to respond
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.register(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:798) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:88) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

Answer (score 0):

you never configure the ssl in your **sample-discovery-service**, so please change generate your p12 keystore file with **-genkeypair**

```
 keytool -genkeypair -alias client -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
```

and config in your sample-discovery-service with the following command

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: 123456
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: client
```

so you can visit in https://localhost:8761/info or https://localhost:8761/actuator/info

Comment: Thanks ! But if you look at my post I already created `keystore.p12`
 using the command as mentioned in my post, still it doesn't works. Are you able to make this working ?

Comment: you only set ssl in sample-client-service, not the sample-discovery-service

Comment: Thanks for the nice suggestion. However I'm getting error posted above in edit-1

Comment: it is impossible to solve all of your problems, this question is about the ssl, i give you the answer and it is ok now, if you still have problem, please raise a new question

Comment: Right agree. However I think this query can be solved if look at the complete code and try to run yourself. Author of the book did not mentioned steps correctly. (Infact no steps)